# Filter a set of data to a specific number of characters before and after a searchword // JSON,CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, text-editing, json, analysis

I have the problem that I have to deal with a set of data given in a JSON/CSV file. I am having four items per entry and one of them has ±5000 characters. I need only a certain range of information that is located around a search word.

How can I filter out ~100 characters before and after a specific search word?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see 100 characters before and after
the word you’re searching for, do

```
grep -oE '.{0,100}word.{0,100}' file
```

or

```
grep –o '.\{0,100\}word.\{0,100\}' file
```